# Visual Studio Massive Git Repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

Somehow visual studio has added to a repo the entire contents of one of my root user folders like so:

[image]

And is currently tracking all 400k files in there.

What would be the best way to untrack these files and make vs git only track a single folder in there?

Comment: Seems you have created a repo to the wrong place. If that's the case, delete the '.git' folder created.

Comment: Looks like you created/initialized a git repo in your user folder. Deleting `c:\users\admin\.git` should fix that.